# How to make a user edit a checkbox name of his/her own choice?

Tags: android, checkbox, edit

I have a list of check boxes that are dynamically created and I want the end user which is using the application to edit the checkbox names as they like.

Example: If the dynamic checkbox name created is checkBox1, the user wants to edit it and save the checkbox name as "Title" How to do this?

Will checkbox.isInEditMode help?

Comment: `checkbox.isInEditMode` won't help. `isInEditMode` lets to distinguish whether you're viewing the xml in the IDE's preview or in the running app. You can place a checkbox and an EditText for the purpose.

Comment: can you post UI what exactly you want to do.  if  you want to change text of checked  checkbox. then you can open dialog box on checked change listner of checkbox and pass view in it, in that user get edittext in which user can edit text and on positive button click you can set that text to checkbox which view is you passed to dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the user input the text using an EditText and then set the value of the text of the checkbox to be that.